# TfrxDBCrossView перенос на следующую строку

Tags: delphi

Добрый день.

Версия FastReport 4.14. Создаю кросс-отчет с заранее неизвестным количеством колонок. Все было бы хорошо, если бы колонки всегда помещались на странице, но нет... Встал вопрос, как осуществлять перенос на следующую строку?

Например, есть бэнд MasterData c набором колонок:

```
Строка 1: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 
Строка 2: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 
Строка 3: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Если на ширину листа вмещаются только 3 колонки, то необходимо переносить колонки ниже:

```
Строка 1: 1, 2, 3,
Строка 2: 4, 5
Строка 3: 1, 2, 3, 
Строка 4: 4, 5 
Строка 5: 1, 2, 3, 
Строка 6: 4, 5
```

Пробовал сделать с помощью TfrxDBCrossView, пробовал и с помощью вертикальных бэндов - в обоих случаях невмещающиеся колонки переносятся на следующую страницу, а надо, чтобы печатались на том же листе ниже. В итоге формирую отчет динамически, добавляя колонки в MasterData и меняя позицию по вертикали для тех, которые не вмещаются. Но уж очень сложно в поддержке, выравнивании, плюс встала задача подгонять ширину колонок по содержимому (в данный момент у всех колонок один размер), а это еще один большой кусок кода.

Хотелось бы узнать, возможно ли решить задачу с помощью компонентов, или, может быть, подскажете способ попроще?